# Play 2.0 application and used plugin both have "Global" object

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10

I've written a Play 2.0 Plugin which redirects all incoming requests to a specific controller. We need this for template developing and testing. To achieve this my plugin hast a global object which looks like this:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {

    Play.application.plugin(classOf[MyPlugin]) match {
      case Some(plugin) => plugin.enabled() match {
        case true => Some(MyController.action)
      }
      case None => super.onRouteRequest(request)
    }

  }

}
```

The problem with this solution is, that I've no possibility to add additional logic to `onRouteRequest` in the main application.

1. Is there another way to achieve this in the plugin then using `onRouteRequest`?
2. Or is there a way to load the `onRouteRequest` plugin logic only when the plugin is enabled?
3. Or is there another way to use two global objects with `onRouteRequest`?

Thanks for help

Torben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plugin should never, ever, ever define a `Global`, that's for the app.

Define a filter instead, and have the app include that in its filters:

```
object MyFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(next: RequestHeader => EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { request =>
    Play.application.plugin(classOf[MyPlugin]) match {
      case Some(plugin) if plugin.enabled() {
        MyController.action(request)
      case _ =>
        next(request)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you James! I'll change this. "and have the app include that in its filters", is this the only way or is it possible to add the filter dynamically from the plugin source if the plugin is enabled?